# cant change CollectionViewCell's size in code iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i have a problem, i want to change CollectionViewCell's size in code but my function doesnt works. Here code of a ViewConroller,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 99
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.textField.text=String(indexPath.row)

        return cell

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 3
        let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 1
        let dim = (collectionView.bounds.width - (cellsAcross - 1) * spaceBetweenCells) / cellsAcross

        return CGSize(width: dim, height: dim)
    }

}
```

function that change size is last

and here code for Cell

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

}
```

when i run my app, size of cell doesnt changes, though i change values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI use following code to customise collection view cell

```
extension SKHodDashBoardViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let width = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 40) / 2

        return CGSize(width:width, height:75);
    }

}
```

Comment: lol it's works i dunno why, code the same as mine 0_0, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First of all, implement `UICollectionViewDataSource` & `UICollectionViewDelegate` + override functions inside your class.

Then inside `viewDidLoad` assign dataSource and delegate to your collection view:

```
self.dataSource = self
self.delegate = self
```

Comment: hi, im trying to do it 
`class ViewController: UICollectionViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate`
but it doesnt works, here is error: 
Redundant conformance of 'ViewController' to protocol 'UICollectionViewDa

Comment: i forgot to say what i have CollectionViewConroller in my stortboard instead of standart ViewController

Comment: Sorry, totally didn't see. Glad you worked it out anyway!